# Diferences between: migrate_d2d and migrate

Tags: migrations

I need to migrate a d7 site to a d7 distribution. This is to migrate from d7 to d7.

I found this modules which I undertand will help me with this task.I've read the documentation but I don't fully understand the diferences between them.

Which one is the right module for my situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Drupal-toDrupal data migration (migrate_d2d)](https://drupal.org/project/migrate_d2d) module page:

> migrate_d2d provides a framework based on the [Migrate API](https://drupal.org/project/migrate)

So the diference is - [migrate](https://drupal.org/project/migrate) is an API module for migrations, and [migrate_d2d](https://drupal.org/project/migrate_d2d) uses it to perform task like yours. Either way you will use [migrate](https://drupal.org/project/migrate), only difference is - do you feel you need to write what authors of [migrate_d2d](https://drupal.org/project/migrate_d2d) already wrote? Or maybe you want to use or modify their work to save some time?

Comment: so, using migrate_d2d will save me to write code that is already written? am I right?

Comment: @chefnelone yes. It will still use migrate in the background. And it will force you to do things the way authors of migrate_d2d decided to go. But migrating from Drupal to Drupal does not leave too wide field for interpretation ;) so it does not hurt.

Comment: @chefnelone and you cannot use migrate directly, as it is an API with no user interface and no "external" interface. It does nothing on it's own (out-of-the-box it only can create, but not read) and always require external code to use it.